# how to explicitly order tasks in the ui on concourse?

Tags: concourse

I have a bunch of examples that are ordered by number. I'd like to be able to keep the order of the tasks as defined in the concourse `pipeline.yml` but on the gui, it gets reordered by the ui.

Is there anyway to explicitly define an order for the tasks on the ui? ie. ex01, ex02 ... ex07 in that order.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe you found out for yourself?

The order in the user interface (Concourse 6.2.0 tested) depends on the string length of the task name.

Short task names come first - longer tasks name names below.

If the task names have all the same length they will be ordered alphabetically.

Have a look at the screenshots:

[task names filled up with underscores](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZtfT.png)

[different task name lengths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meOxW.png)

Comment: awesome that helps alot.